# Query to get top 5 across months

Tags: google-sheets

(Google Sheets) I have a set of transaction data that grows as the year goes on.  I want to pull out the top 5 vendors based on grand total, and present the vendor in the first column, sum of Jan's transactions in the 2nd column, Feb in 3rd, etc.  A vendor may have more than one transaction per month, so I need to sum them before sorting and deciding who are the top 5.

I was trying to kludge it together by making columns 1 (Vendor) and 2 (Jan) populate with this:
=query('Data'!A:K,"Select D, Sum(K) Where
A >= date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE("1/1/2022"),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' AND A<= date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE("1/31/2022"),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
Group by D Order by Sum(K) Desc Limit 5",0)

And column 3 (Feb) populate with this:
=query('Data'!A:K,"Select K Where
A >= date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE("2/1/2022"),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' AND A<= date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE("2/28/2022"),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
Order by K Desc Limit 5",0)

D-Vendor, K-Amount, A-Date

But I cant seem to get this to work (because doing the Feb set formula seems to want me to present the vendor column again.)  And I don't blame it.  It's definitely not ideal.  Plus, I think I'm having problems with the top 5 order based on January being different when other months data is added.  Is there a better way?

I feel like a great alternative would be to query off the pivot table I built, but I cant seem to figure out how to do that.  (or if there was a way to show top 5, group all the others in pivot table easily..).

Edit: adding link to a google sheet that's kind if what I'm looking for but with fake data
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13tYeCgA4mkrtkeMVGqRlQprESNlFh9NXc6MlkYbpwho/edit#gid=0

Edit2: Expanded with a Department field.  I can seem to get it doing a sortn, but that's not very dynamic and wont hold up without surgery next month.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: you say `because doing the Feb set formula seems to want me to present the vendor column again` ... but may be the top 5 vendors will not be the same between Jan and Feb, there is no other solution to give the top 5 vendors for both monthes together if you don't want to have 2 vendor's columns

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13tYeCgA4mkrtkeMVGqRlQprESNlFh9NXc6MlkYbpwho/edit?usp=sharing
This isn't the spreadsheet since it's for work, but this is the idea.  And I only pulled for top 2 instead of 5 since I don't have that much data in this set.  The highlighted area is where I've got the query formulas.  
I'd like to pull out Bob and Alice - who have the largest Grand Totals.  See Query formulas in F14 and H15.

Comment: Added another Layer, so formulas now in G19 and I20, want to pull out Alice and Carol instead for the Marketing Department.

Comment: I might have an idea, built something very similar for my company for our products (group ranked by category, then internal ranked again). But would like to know if this data is automatically populated/manually typed/uploaded via csv from another system?

https://prnt.sc/huHYuoVqQRjp

Comment: My method would require a few tabs to basically act as data processors so that what you want to achieve is fully automated without you having to do surgery every time you need a new report. Usually I would built tabs for:

***Input --> Data Cleaners --> Data Processors --> Output***

It can run for a long time as long your definitions/process/data structure does change.

Comment: @LucasLui888 The data that you circled in red comes from a filter(importrange(fromanotherworksheet etc)) formula.  The source table for the filter(importrange) will grow longer each month by me manually cutting a copy of the new rows, and pasting it at the bottom.  So original is manual, but into this specific spreadsheet, it comes by filter(importrange)